# Rails 3.1, after_update procedure doesn't accept method parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm hoping there's something obvious I'm missing here, I can't think of a reason why you shouldn't be able to pass method parameters in the after_update call:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :create_thumb(100)

  def create_thumb(size)
    ...
```

This won't boot.  If I hardcode the size in the method it works fine.  Is there some funky syntax to do this or is it not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a Proc and call the method inside of that:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update { create_thumb(100) }

  def create_thumb(size)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks.  These little things are so hard for a novice to figure out from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value on the method like this:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :create_thumb

  def create_thumb(size = 100)
    ...
```

Comment: In practice, there's really no difference between this and just hardcoding `size` into the method. It's a default value, but it can't be changed because one still wouldn't be able to pass in a different value and override the default.